# asXML() gives error if remove echo, how to solve it?

Tags: php, xml

I am using following code to create xml file:

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
    $track = $xml->addChild('Account');

    /* Add Attribute */
    $track->addAttribute("name","aa");

    $track->addChild('name', 'abc');
    $track->addChild('mobile', '989875');

    Header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');        
    $filename = 'file/abc.xml';             

    echo $xml->asXML();             

    $file = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($file,$xml->asXML());
    fclose($file);
```

but if i remove echo from this line `echo $xml->asXML();` then it gives me following error:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found    Line Number 1, Column 1:

and also i am not able to save xml using asXML() function, so i use fwrite, it create the file.

so what is the problem? why it gives the error? why asXML($filename) not save the file?

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: What is *it*?  Does PHP give you this error?  Or is it from the browser?  This kinda looks like a Firefox error.  Try to view the source of the page, and see if there is anything in there.

Comment: What error does `asXML($filename)` give you?  That should work.

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat, the asXML($filename) is not able to save xml file, so i use fwrite to create xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is *not* from PHP!  It's from Firefox.  You are sending `Header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');` so the browser is expecting an XML file to be sent.

When you do `echo $xml->asXML();`, you are doing just that.  The browser then parses the XML file and shows it to you.

Without the `echo`, you are sending a blank page and telling the browser to parse that as XML.  That's why it's saying "no element found".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just want to create a file, so there is no need of `header` line,right?

Comment: The `header()` line adds a value to the header that's returned to the client (browser).  In your case, it's not needed.